# Error: Janrain authentication

Tags: authentication, connected-apps, auth-provider

I followed the janrain Auth provider tutorial for social login implementation and getting following error:

- https://ap1.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_Token&ErrorDescription=Access+token+was+not+returned

> There was a problem with your authentication attempt. Please try again. If you continue to encounter problems, contact your administrator.

I guess what I have missed in the tutorial (http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_janrain.htm&language=en_US#sso_provider_janrain) is point 8 where it is advised to edit Registration Handler class to edit content before using it.

Kindly let me know what and where exactly i need to edit in this class ?

Answer (score 0):

In the code generated for janRain widget, you need to provide your callback url (generated via. Auth. Provider settings).
Hope this helps.
Thnks